# SVG Circle element jumps upon scale transform

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Below is the code to have a circle and scale it on mouseover using D3. It does what it is supposed to do but also takes cricle to somewhere else, meaning circle scales and jumps(translates) to some other location. I cannot apprehend the cause for it.

```
this.node = this.chartLayer.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", (d) => { return this.colors(d.group); })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(' + 2 + ')');
        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with D3 (be it v3 or v4). The problem here is that `scale` is centered at the origin (0,0) of the SVG, which is the top left corner. Because of this, any element that is not on that position (0,0) will seem to move.

Have a look at this (hover over the circle):

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(' + 2 + ')');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

**Solution**: translate the element to the origin before the scale:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(-150,-75) scale(' + 2 + ')');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

**D3 Solution (way better)**: simply change the radius of the circle:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('r', 40);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

**EDIT**: Using getters, you can change the attribute without hardcoding it. For instance, getting the radius of the circle and doubling it on `mouseover` and dividing it by half on `mouseout`:

```js
var circle = d3.select("circle");
circle.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var r = d3.select(this).attr('r')
    d3.select(this).attr('r', r*2);
}).on('mouseout', function(d) {
    var r = d3.select(this).attr('r')
    d3.select(this).attr('r', r/2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
 <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="20" fill="teal"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: great answer @gerardo-furtado. I like the radius solution but is there a way to apply a scale factor to radius upon mouseover and go back to normal on mouseout?

Comment: I think I will have to keep track of mouseover node and its radius and use the stored valued to revert back.

Comment: I wrote this answer just to show you the issue with "scale". If you have a force directed chart, just change the radius based on the datum or on any hardcoded value. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve it using radius method. it works great, I used the same approach. And yes, I have a force directed chart, when I drag the circle, sometimes it takes a while to revert back, I guess thats because of force simulation ticks. And by now you might have guessed that I am just beginning to learn D3 and SVG animation/manipulation.

Comment: It seems when I drag a node and leave it, `mouseout` doesn't happen, so I guess I will have to handle this situation in mouseup or drag end.

Comment: That's a bit tricky... for this last issue, I suggest you post *another* question.

Comment: It is solved by checking a flag on drag end. Thanks @gerardo-furtado, I really liked the quick yet detailed answer.